# Proving that these equalities are true.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I really am at wits end with this assignment. To no avail, my attempts, the only assignments that I cannot do in my workbook. Have a look:

$$x^{2n}-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-2x\cos\frac{k \pi}{n}+1) \\ . \\ 
x^{2n+1}-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-2x\cos\frac{k \pi}{2n+1}+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you need that formula only for $x \in \mathbb R$,
the "generalization" to complex numbers is easier to obtain.

For $z \in \mathbb C$, the equation $z^{2n} = 1$ has the complex roots
$z_k = \exp(\frac{i\pi k}{n})$, $k = 0, \dots, 2n-1$, therefore
$$
 z^{2n} - 1 = \prod_{k=0}^{2n-1} (z - z_k) \quad . 
$$
Your first equation follows from
$$
 (z - z_0)(z - z_n) = (z-1)(z+1) = z^2 - 1
$$
and combining the remaining terms for $k$ and $2n-k$ ($k = 1, \ldots, n)$:
$$
 (z - z_k)(z - z_{2n-k}) = \bigl(z - \exp(\frac{i\pi k}{n})\bigr)
  \bigl(z - \exp(-\frac{i\pi k}{n})\bigr) \\
 = z^2 + z \bigl(\exp(\frac{i\pi k}{n}) + \exp(-\frac{i\pi k}{n})\bigr) + 1\\
 = z^2 + 2 z \cos \frac {\pi k}{n}  + 1 \, .
$$

In a similar fashion you get
$$
z^{2n+1} - 1 = (z-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n} \bigl(
z^2 + 2 z \cos \frac {2\pi k}{2n+1} + 1 \bigr)
$$
which seems to be the correct version of your second equation.